# Export thousand of variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want export many variables something like this

```
const ENUMS = {
    ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH      : 52,
    ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH      : 36,
    SZNAME_LENGTH           : 20,
    // ... and 1000 more variables 
}

export { ... ENUMS } // ERROR
```

I want to access each variable directly by its name from other script

```
var value = ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH
```

... without have to use ENUMS object eg:

```
var value = ENUMS.ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH
```

how can I accomplish that, thanks

Syntax Error using Node.JS

Comment: *What* error do you get?

Comment: This all sounds like a really bad idea. Jamming that many things in the namespace, even if you could do it easily, is far from ideal. Secondly, consider `let` or `const` instead of old-school `var` here. If you do want to ignore how JavaScript prefers to have encapsulation, you can just force-inject all that into the `global` namespace, but this is considered extremely "rude".

Comment: Can't you export `ENUMS` and then `import { FOO } from "./enums.mjs"`?

Comment: @tadman the error was ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'```. Is populating `global` will affect performance ? Context: I am writing an emulator originally writen in C++, I need it as fast as possible. I used `var` because some says it much faster than `let`.

Comment: Don't believe Internet folklore like that without testing it; it's extremely unlikely to be true. There's no real difference between what you expect `export { ... ENUMS }` to do and just exporting `ENUMS` directly; your attempt would just make a shallow copy of `ENUMS` anyway.

Comment: I'm *extremely* suspicious of any claims about `let` being slower than `var`, at least on any modern JavaScript implementation. Secondly, the number of variables shouldn't directly impact performance here, but that is an alarming number of "globals", something we should all strive to minimize. Honestly, is `import C from 'consts'` and then using `C.XYZ` the worst thing ever? It avoids *considerable* namespace clutter.

Comment: I'd also suggest that before you bake all this into any new code you evaluate the alternative: A configuration file (e.g. JSON) where you can define these, and then read that in and use it like `C.account.name.length` and `C.account.password.length` etc.

Comment: @pointy yep, I can `import { FOO } from "./enums.mjs"`. I was asking about the `export *`

Comment: @Jupri well what about `export ENUM;`? You don't have to *import* all of it; that's what the destructuring is for.

Comment: @Pointy, I try `export ENUM;` with error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Comment: Well that means you're not in an EJS module; you need to fix that first.

Comment: @Pointy `export ENUM` is a syntax error in standard JavaScript, what do you mean by EJS? Did you mean `export default ENUM`?

Comment: @Bergi yea; whatever works; I almost never do something like this (maybe literally never) so right, `export default ENUM;` to export the whole object for destructuring in the `import` statements elsewhere. Honestly I think that whatever the goal is here, there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @Jupri Why do you have thousands of variables in that module? And do you really need all thousands of variables in the module where you want to import it?

Comment: @Bergi, not 1000 exacly, just to many to type...

Comment: @Jupri Too many to type an import declaration, or too many to type export declarations?

Answer (score 2):

```js
// consts.js
export const ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH = 32
export const ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH = 42
...


// app.js
import {ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH, ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH} from "./consts.js"
```

just repeat for your 1000 variables… or bite the bullet and use a namespace import.

Comment: This is accepable answer, but I am to lazy to type it all 1000 export lines, I wish there's syntax `export { ... ENUMS }` and `import { * } from "enums.js"`

Comment: @Jupri [There is no wildcard import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35554526/1048572) in JS, and [for good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564110/1048572)

Comment: @Jupri import/export syntax is designed to be statically analyzed, which is why you won't find your desired ... export syntax.  Quite frankly for your use case I would relax the "without using the ENUMS object" constraint.  Just export and import the object.  importing code can alias it to a shorter name like `E`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to expose all the properties as variables without specifically importing them.

First, I want to clarify that this is generally not a good idea, clutters up the scope and might lead to variables inadvertently overriding each other if the other module contains similarly named variables.

Second, this solution uses the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), which is deprecated and generally not considered a good practice (see the note on MDN)

Having said that:

```js
// enums.js
export const ENUMS = {
    ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH      : 52,
    ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH      : 36,
    SZNAME_LENGTH           : 20,
    // ... and 1000 more variables 
}

// then in the other module
import { ENUMS } from './enums.js';

with (ENUMS) {
  // you can use ENUMS properties here as variables
  // not a good idea!
  console.log(ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH)  // 52
}
```

Comment: `with` is forbidden in strict mode, but an ES6 module will implicitly be strict mode

Answer (score 0):

Heyo guys, thank you for your all in sight. greatly appreciated. I end up with something like this,

in enums.js

```
const ENUMS = {
    ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH      : 52,
    ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH      : 36,
    SZNAME_LENGTH           : 20,
    // and many more...
}
   
export default ENUMS
```

in other files :

```
import ENUMS from './enum.js'

// just need 3 of them here ...
const {
    ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH,
    ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH,
    SZNAME_LENGTH,
} = ENUMS
```

Comment: If you need only a few of the variables in the importing module, and want to destructure them into individual bindings, you really should use named exports instead and just type the three names in the import declaration.

Comment: @Bergi, I wrap all inside `const ENUMS` because I need to process it before exporting whole attributes, eg: flip ENUMS become => `{ 52: "ACCOUNTNAME_LENGTH", 36: "ACCOUNTPASS_LENGTH", .... }`